# What is the correct partial derivative of $Y^c$ with respect to $A_{ij}^{kc}$?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, math, derivative, grad-cam++

I have a question about the [Grad-CAM++ paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11063.pdf). I do not understand how the following equation (10) for the alphas is obtained:
$$
\alpha_{ij}^{kc} =
\frac{\frac{\partial^2 Y^c}{(\partial A_{ij}^k)^2}}
{2\frac{\partial^2 Y^c}{(\partial A_{ij}^k)^2}
  + \sum_{ab} A_{ab}^k \{ \frac{\partial^3 Y^c}{(\partial A_{ij}^k)^3} \}}
\qquad (10)
$$
I found various issues with the derivation, here I will focus on the step from equation (7) to (8).

Equation (7) without the relu function is:
$$
    Y^c =
    \sum_k \Bigl( \Bigl\{ \sum_{a,b} \alpha_{ab}^{kc}
    \cdot \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ab}^k} \Bigr\}
    \Bigl[ \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}^k \Bigr] \Bigr)
    \qquad (7)
$$
Here $Y^c$ is supposed to be a function of the $A_{ij}^k$, and $\alpha_{ab}^{kc}$ are unknowns to be determined.

The next step consists of computing the partial derivative of (7) w.r.t. $A_{ij}^{kc}$, which according to the paper yields equation (8):
$$
  \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{jk}^k} = \sum_{a,b} \alpha_{ab}^{kc}
  \cdot \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ab}^k} +
    \sum_{a,b} A_{ab}^k \Bigl\{ \alpha_{ij}^{kc}
    \cdot \frac{\partial^2 Y^c}{(\partial A_{jk}^k)^2} \Bigr\}
    \qquad (8)
$$
However, when I did the computation myself I got the following:
$$
  \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ij}^k} =
    \sum_{a,b} \alpha_{ab}^{kc} \cdot \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ab}^k} +
    \sum_l \Bigl(\Bigl[\sum_{u,v} A_{uv}^l \Bigr]
    \Bigl\{ \sum_{a,b} \alpha_{ab}^{lc} \cdot
    \frac{\partial^2 Y^c}{\partial A_{ij}^k \partial A_{ab}^l} \Bigr\} \Bigr)
    \qquad (8')
$$
Note the extra sum, and the cross-derivatives.

What is right, (8) or (8')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reflection I noticed that the actual final expression should contain derivatives of the alphas w.r.t. $A_{ij}^k$ too, because the alphas cannot be constants that do not depend on $A_{ij}^k$.  So, the equation becomes:
$$
\frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ij}^k} = 
\sum_{a,b} \alpha_{ab}^{kc} \cdot \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ab}^k} +
\sum_l \Bigl(\Bigl[\sum_{u,v} A_{uv}^l \Bigr] 
\Bigl\{ \sum_{a,b} \alpha_{ab}^{lc} \cdot
\frac{\partial^2 Y^c}{\partial A_{ij}^k \partial A_{ab}^l} \Bigr\} \Bigr) + 
\sum_l \Bigl( \Bigl[\sum_{u,v} A_{uv}^l\Bigr] 
\Bigl\{ \sum_{a,b} \frac{\partial \alpha_{ab}^{lc}}{\partial A_{ij}^k} \cdot \frac{\partial Y^c}{\partial A_{ab}^l} \Bigr\} \Bigr) 
$$
More details in the appendix of [this document](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/%7Emlerma/papers-and-preprints/Grad_CAM___is_equivalent_to_Grad_CAM_with_positive_gradients.pdf).

I believe this is the final answer to my question.